# Встраивание графиков в виджете

Tags: python, qlayout, pyqt6, pyqtgraph, qmainwindow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается вывести 2 графика в Главном окне. Почему-то выводится один график и тот центрированный.

Хотелось бы видеть графики в определенных местах, например, один ближе к левому верхнему углу, а другой ближе к правому углу.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMessageBox, QAbstractItemView
from two_graph import Ui_FirstWindow
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        x1 = [12, 34, 33, 54, 67, 72, 85]
        y1 = [20, 44, 53, 90, 11, 2, 5]

        x2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        y2 = [120, 244, 453, 490, 411, 12, 25]

        self.widgetGraph1 = self.ui.widget1

        self.ui.widget1 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 1')
        self.ui.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 81, 55))
        self.ui.widget1.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.ui.widget1.setObjectName("widgetGraph1")
        self.ui.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.layout.setContentsMargins(15, 90, 0, 0)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.widgetGraph2 = self.ui.widget2

        self.ui.widget2 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 2')
        self.ui.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 81, 55))
        self.ui.widget2.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.ui.widget2.setObjectName("widgetGraph2")
        self.ui.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.layout.setContentsMargins(15, 90, 0, 0)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget2, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.plot1(x1, y1)
        self.plot2(x2, y2)

    def plot1(self, x1, y1):
        self.ui.widget1.clear()
        self.ui.widget1.plot(x1, y1, pen= 'g')
        self.ui.widget1.setBackground((235, 235, 235))
        self.ui.widget1.setLabel('left', 'X', )
        self.ui.widget1.setLabel('bottom', 'Y', )

    def plot2(self, x2, y2):
        self.ui.widget2.clear()
        self.ui.widget2.plot(x2, y2, pen= 'r')
        self.ui.widget2.setBackground((235, 235, 235))
        self.ui.widget2.setLabel('left', 'X2', )
        self.ui.widget2.setLabel('bottom', 'Y2', )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**two_graph.py**

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(780, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 311, 191))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 290, 311, 191))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(FirstWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 780, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        FirstWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "Главное окно"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FirstWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
    ui.setupUi(FirstWindow)
    FirstWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: QChartView смотрели? https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/chart_line__QtChart.py#L9

Comment: Смотрел, но пока не понимаю, как это поможет выставить нужные координаты графиков в окне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется встраивание виджетов в Qt Designer, вы можете найти похожие вопросы с подробным описанием как это делается. 
А выглядит это примерно так:

**q1443835_main.py**

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, \
    QLineEdit, QMenu, QMessageBox, QAbstractItemView
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1443835_two_graph import Ui_FirstWindow                             

import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        x1 = [12, 34, 33, 54, 67, 72, 85]
        y1 = [20, 44, 53, 90, 11, 2, 5]

        x2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        y2 = [120, 244, 453, 490, 411, 12, 25]

# ??? vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        '''
        self.widgetGraph1 = self.ui.widget1

        self.ui.widget1 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 1')
        self.ui.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 81, 55))
        self.ui.widget1.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.ui.widget1.setObjectName("widgetGraph1")
        
        self.ui.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.layout.setContentsMargins(15, 90, 0, 0)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.widgetGraph2 = self.ui.widget2
        self.ui.widget2 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 2')
        self.ui.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 81, 55))
        self.ui.widget2.setFixedSize(250, 100)
        self.ui.widget2.setObjectName("widgetGraph2")
        
        self.ui.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.layout.setContentsMargins(15, 90, 0, 0)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        '''
# ??? ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.ui.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
# ----------------------------------------------> vvvv <--------------------        
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# ----------------------------------------------> ^^^^ <--------------------

        self.plot1(x1, y1)
        self.plot2(x2, y2)

    def plot1(self, x1, y1):
        self.ui.widget1.clear()
        self.ui.widget1.plot(x1, y1, pen= 'g')
        self.ui.widget1.setBackground((235, 235, 235))
        self.ui.widget1.setLabel('left', 'X', )
        self.ui.widget1.setLabel('bottom', 'Y', )

    def plot2(self, x2, y2):
        self.ui.widget2.clear()
        self.ui.widget2.plot(x2, y2, pen= 'r')
        self.ui.widget2.setBackground((235, 235, 235))
        self.ui.widget2.setLabel('left', 'X2', )
        self.ui.widget2.setLabel('bottom', 'Y2', )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1443835_two_graph.py**

```
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg                                                    # !!! +++


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(780, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        
#        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 1')                    # !!! +++
        
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 311, 191))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        
#        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2 = pg.PlotWidget(title='График 2')                    # !!! +++

        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 290, 311, 191))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        
        '''
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(FirstWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 780, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        FirstWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        '''
        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "Главное окно"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! 
Первое: правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае надо корректировать файл, который сгенерировал QtDesigner? Где-то читал, что нельзя менять файл, сформированный им.

Второе: могли бы уточнить, вы здесь сделали акцент на добавленные строки?
```
# ----------------------------------------------> vvvv <--------------------        
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.ui.widget2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# ----------------------------------------------> ^^^^ <--------------------
```
Что значат четыре цифры после widget?

Comment: @AndrewGans да, это делается в Qt Designer и называется встраивание виджетов и вы можете найти на данном ресурсе вопросы где я подробно описывал как это делать. И это не относится к тому, что вы читали мои рекомендации о том , что не надо изменять  код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Абсолютное позиционирование это плохая практика,  поэтому я акцентировал ваше внимание, сто вам надо изучить менеджеры компоновки. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: если не трудно, можете скинуть ссылки ресурсы, чтобы я прочитал то, что нужно?

Comment: @AndrewGans https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Я прочитал, но мой вопрос все-таки про другое был. Посмотрите на картинку в прикреплении и расположение виджетов на нем. В вашем случае не понятно, как двигать графики, координаты выставить, чтобы левый верхний угол находился там, где надо.

Comment: Да, и если мне нужно добавить 3-ий график, то он уходит вниз под второй, т.е. в линию 3 графика не получается выстроить.

Comment: @AndrewGans вы спросили: "Не получается вывести 2 графика в Главном окне. Почему-то выводится один график и тот центрированный. Хотелось бы видеть графики в определенных местах, например, один ближе к левому верхнему углу, а другой ближе к правому углу.". Я вам ответил. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос. The END.